# Cocos2D logging "[Action update]. override me" in every tick

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

Is this a problem? I believe that the warning:
`[Action update]. override me`
comes from directly calling [myAction update] on my own action. Which I'm not doing.

Can I just comment out the log warning? This gives me a dirty feeling. But everything seems to work fine...

This was in Cocos2D 1.1 and also in 2.0rc2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably created a class that inherits from CCAction. Some code in CCAction will call the 'update' method. So 1) either you did not provide an 'update' method in your class, or 2) in your classe's update method your are invoking [super update]. If you *really* have nothing to do in the update cycle, just put an empty procedure in your class.

```
-(void) update:(ccTime) dt{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `[CCEaseOut actionWithDuration:xxx]`